# React Native Pass Selected asyncStorage value to Popup onPress

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, asyncstorage, react-native-popup-menu, react-native-modal

I'm trying to make a popup screen for the value I have selected. Which is in the localstorage.

I am trying to pass the value firstname, lastname, phone to Popup.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9t1X.gif)

I want the value "h" to show up next to 'Call' and 'Text'.

```
      {
    favContact.map((obj,i)=>{
      return (
        <View style={[HomePageStyles.ContactList, {width:95}]}>

        {/* CONTACT CALL/MESSAGE POPUP */}
        <ContactPopup Popup={Popup} setPopup={setPopup} />

        {/* CONTACT  */}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setPopup(true)}
        }>

            {/* CONTACT ICON */}
            { showIcon }

            {/* CONTACT NAME */}
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[Fonts.ContactNameFonts, {textAlign:'center', fontSize:11, paddingHorizontal:15}]}>{obj.firstname}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {/* END OF CONTACT */}
        </View>
            )
          })
        }
```

This is my Favorite Contact Page.

```
<Modal isVisible={props.Popup} hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true}
backdropTransitionOutTiming={0}
onBackdropPress={() => props.setPopup(false)}
onSwipeComplete={() => props.setPopup(false)}
swipeDirection="down"
animationInTiming={550} animationOutTiming={850}>

  <View style={AddPopupStyles.Container}>

    <View style={AddPopupStyles.ImgCont}>

      <Image style={AddPopupStyles.Img}source={require('../assets/icons/swipe.png')}/>

    </View>

    <Text style={AddPopupStyles.Heading}>{firstname}{lastname}</Text>

      <TouchableOpacity style={AddPopupStyles.TextCont}
                        onPress = {() => Communications.phonecall( phone , true)}        
      >
        <Text style={AddPopupStyles.Text}>Call {firstname}{lastname}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={AddPopupStyles.TextCont}
                        onPress={()  => Communications.text(phone, 'Hey ' + firstname + ', im in need of a Ryde. Are you able to pick me up? This is my current location: ' )}
      >
        <Text style={AddPopupStyles.Text}>Text</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={AddPopupStyles.TextCont}
        onPress={() => {props.setPopup(false)}}
      >
        <Text style={[AddPopupStyles.Text, AddPopupStyles.CancelText]}>
          Cancel
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>

</Modal>
```

This is my pop up page.

Please help me masters.

Comment: using props in popup page you can do that. for example first name and last name what ever you are using pass it props and while .clicking on any contact instead of directly calling setPop(true) create a method and pass obj from .map and then from that obj pass the value of firstname, lastname. let me know if this helps or you need any sample

Comment: Hi, a sample would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Apparently, my setPopup was duplicate. I had other popup pages with same setpopup, thus not showing the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     {
    favContact.map((obj,i)=>{
      return (
        <View style={[HomePageStyles.ContactList, {width:95}]}>

        {/* CONTACT CALL/MESSAGE POPUP */}
        <ContactPopup Popup={Popup} setPopup={setPopup} details = {this.state.popupDetails} />

        {/* CONTACT  */}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.onPressContact(obj)}
        }>

            {/* CONTACT ICON */}
            { showIcon }

            {/* CONTACT NAME */}
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[Fonts.ContactNameFonts, {textAlign:'center', fontSize:11, paddingHorizontal:15}]}>{obj.firstname}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {/* END OF CONTACT */}
        </View>
            )
          })
        }


    onPressContact = (contactDetails) => {
          this.setState({popupDetails: contactDetails})
          setPopup(true)
       }

and next in popup screen 

    <Modal isVisible={props.Popup} hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true}
backdropTransitionOutTiming={0}
onBackdropPress={() => props.setPopup(false)}
onSwipeComplete={() => props.setPopup(false)}
swipeDirection="down"
animationInTiming={550} animationOutTiming={850}>

  <View style={AddPopupStyles.Container}>

    <View style={AddPopupStyles.ImgCont}>

      <Image style={AddPopupStyles.Img}source={require('../assets/icons/swipe.png')}/>

    </View>

    <Text style={AddPopupStyles.Heading}>{props.details.firstname}{props.details.lastname}</Text>

      <TouchableOpacity style={AddPopupStyles.TextCont}
                        onPress = {() => Communications.phonecall( phone , true)}        
      >
        <Text style={AddPopupStyles.Text}>Call {props.details.firstname}{props.details.lastname}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={AddPopupStyles.TextCont}
                        onPress={()  => Communications.text(phone, 'Hey ' + props.details.firstname + ', im in need of a Ryde. Are you able to pick me up? This is my current location: ' )}
      >
        <Text style={AddPopupStyles.Text}>Text</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={AddPopupStyles.TextCont}
        onPress={() => {props.setPopup(false)}}
      >
        <Text style={[AddPopupStyles.Text, AddPopupStyles.CancelText]}>
          Cancel
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>

</Modal>
```

In brief, here what i have done is on click of contact i'm calling a function onPressContact and storing the obj of that particular contact and then sending to popup using details props in contactPopup